# How To Reset Curve Profile with Script

Tags: bezier-curves

how can i remove all points or reset curve to default ? (use code)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following. All is commented below:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object

# Get the modifier
bevel = obj.modifiers["Bevel"]

# Get custom points
points = bevel.custom_profile.points

# Keep only 2
while len(points) > 2:
    points.remove(points[1]) #Can't remove at 0 (don't know why)

# Reset locations
points[0].location = (1,0)
points[1].location = (0,1)

# Update the profile
bevel.custom_profile.update()
```

Note: the window won't update until you move the cursor over it.

Comment: It's work, thank you :)

Comment: Maybe removing 0 would be removing the head of a crude linked list.. the whole list would become inaccessible memory.